# Error of "Object Required" for copy an array value

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have the error message of

> Object Required

at the line of `hostname(X, 1).Copy`

I have used msgbox to test this line and the hostname for this array can be found, but just this line of code has error message. The hostname for this array value is W01GOPTIMAPP1A.

The related code is

```
wSlastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    hostname = WintelSheet.Range("B1:B" & wSlastRow).Value2
    '// Now Loop through each row
    For X = 2 To wSlastRow

    If Not IsError(.Range("AI" & X).Value) Then
        If IsDate(.Range("AI" & X)) Then

        '//Calculate the last day of the month for dates in Column W (dtStart) and first day of the next current month (dtFinal)
        dtStart = DateSerial(Year(.Range("AI" & X)), Month(.Range("AI" & X)) + 1, 1)
        dtFinal = DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now) + 1, 1)
        With AparSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("J:L")
        .Columns(3).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & dtStart, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<" & dtFinal
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0)
            NumberOfPasteRows = .Rows(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1))) Then
                .EntireRow.Copy Destination:=GeneratedSheet.Rows(wSLastPasteRow & ":" & (wSLastPasteRow + NumberOfPasteRows - 1))
                hostname(X, 1).Copy
                GeneratedSheet.Range("B" & wSLastPasteRow).Resize(NumberOfPasteRows - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                wSLastPasteRow = wSLastPasteRow + NumberOfPasteRows - 1

            End If
            End With
        End With
        End With
        End If
    End If
    Next X
```

Comment: Since hostname is allready an array you could just reference it directly in the GeneratedSheet like so: GeneratedSheet.Range("B" & wSLastPasteRow) = hostname(X, 1)?

Comment: What do you expect to be in `WintelSheet.Range("B1:B" & wSlastRow).Value2`? Your 'hostname' variable is *not* a `Range` object.

Comment: I have tried this `hostname(X, 1) = GeneratedSheet.Range("B" & wSLastPasteRow).Resize(NumberOfPasteRows - 1).value` but there's no value copied over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted code is incomplete but based on behavior "hostname" is declared as Variant, or it is a Variant if it's not declared

When you perform this operation `hostname = WintelSheet.Range("B1:B" & wSlastRow).Value2` you assign the values from a Range object to a Variant (array)

The Range object has a method called ".Copy", the Variant doesn't

**Edit:**

To be able to copy from `hostname` declare it as a Range object:

```
Dim hostname As Range
Set hostname = WintelSheet.Range("B1:B" & wSlastRow)

hostname(x, 1).Copy
```

or simply use the range itself:

```
WintelSheet.Range("B" & wSlastRow).Copy
```

Comment: I see, then how should I assign this value, like `hostname(X, 1) =
                GeneratedSheet.Range("B" & wSLastPasteRow).Resize(NumberOfPasteRows - 1).value`?

Comment: I have tried with this, but the result isn't correct